# How to make a command block summon an end crystal on top of said command block in Minecraft 1.14.1

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to put a command into a command block that will spawn an invulnerable end crystal directly on top of the command block relative to the command block's location in world.

This is the current command I am putting in the command block minus any tag for offset since the offset is what I am trying to figure out.

```
/summon minecraft:end_crystal ~ ~1 ~ {PersistenceRequired:1b,Attributes:[{Name:"generic.knockbackResistance",Base:1f}],Invulnerable:1}
```

Specific question: How do I put an offset in the command block command in order to get my desired result above?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me like you've answered yourself, as you already have an "offset" in the command (the `~ ~1 ~` part).

If the question is towards the base of the end crystal being inside the command block, that's just because of it's unusually sized hitbox and texture. To fix this I made the command block summon the end crystal 0.5 blocks higher up, and the output was this:

[image: End Crystal on top of Command Block]

Either way, the command you supplied works perfectly fine in 1.14.1.

Comment: Oh, I thought that was world coordinates and using the ~ for relative was just so it showed up at the command block's location otherwise it would show up at that coordinate in the world. Alright then, thank you. Sorry for the, now really silly feeling, question. Kinda a command block noob here.